# How to play GameObject (ParticleSystem) and stop?

Tags: unity, c#

Have a game where you've to shoot somethings and when you hit the GameObject I've should play. I've tried with `Instantiate` but I can keep shooting even if the gameobject is destroyed. What should I do in order to fix it?

```
 public GameObject particlesystem;

 void Start () {
    particlesystem= GameObject.Find("Effect");
 }

 void Hit(){
 Destroy(gameobject)
 Instantiate(particlesystem, transform.position, transform.rotation);
 }
```

This is how I handle it now, but as I wrote earlier I can keep activating the particle system.

Answer (score 1):

[Particle System](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html)

Get your particle system in code and use public methods like `Play()` and `Stop()`.

Just as an example of use:

```
this._particleSystems[i].Play();
if (Time.time > 50) {
    this._particleSystems[i].Stop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best way to do it is, instead of

```
particlesystem= GameObject.Find("Effect");
```

assign the prefab in the unity GUI (in the script field)

In addition, when you want to play the effect you should have to do it this way

```
var gO = Instantiate(particlesystem, transform.position, transform.rotation);
Destroy(gO, seconds);
```

I don't remember if var is a gameobject or an object type, but with var it should work.

Edit: if you have to destroy the game object (which are you shooting) call destroy(gameobject) too